# Spring RMI - Lookup of RMI stub failed

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I am using Spring 3.2 and am getting the following error when attempting to create a bean definition based on a "remote" RMI service. Both the client and the server have been implemented on the same host.

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: 
Lookup of RMI stub failed; nested exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException.
```

I am attempting to deploy to Glassfish 3.1.2. The code involved looks as follows-

spring-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Remoting Config (server) -->
<bean id="testRmiService" class="com.test.backend.rmi.TestRmiServiceImpl" />
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="CountryService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="testRmiService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.test.backend.rmi.TestRmiService"/>
    <property name="registryPort" value="1099"/>
</bean>


<!-- Remoting Config (client) -->
<bean id="helloService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://localhost:1099/CountryService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.test.backend.rmi.TestRmiService"/>
</bean>
```

```java
package com.test.backend.rmi;

public interface TestRmiService {

public String doSomething();
}
```

```java
package com.test.backend.rmi;

public class TestRmiServiceImpl implements TestRmiService {

    public String doSomething() {
        return "hello";
    } 

}
```

I checked using netstat and the service appears to be running on port 1099.
Any ideas are appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that Glassfish does not like RMI connections opened through the "back door". I'd rather suggest implementing remoting through the HTTP Invoker: http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-remoting-by-http-invoker-example